# Imgur API - use specified gallery/directory to upload into

Tags: android, image-uploading, imgur

I have read Imgur's API documentation: https://api.imgur.com
Uploading process seems very easy to implement, but links seems to be random. I would like to add all the images uploaded by application to a separated gallery. So this should contains only app users' images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

[add images to an album](https://api.imgur.com/endpoints/album#album-add-to)

Comment: Could you share please also an example?

Comment: did u manage to get an example? also in need of one, anonymous upload works @KovacsAkos